# Adding specified masked areas of a pixel grid together. Does the result completely mask a certain other area?

Tags: image, math, data-structures, geometry, image-segmentation

Given a grid of pixels and a list of certain areas on the grid, how do you find if all those areas in the list, when combined, completely cover a certain area of the grid?

I have an image, which we can think of as a grid of pixels. Certain rectangular parts of the image have a mask applied by us. We have a list of the location/sizes of these masks. We would like to know if adding all the masked areas in our list together would completely mask a certain other area on the image.

Is there a good algorithm or data structure that is suited to help solve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can build union of mask rectangles with line sweep algorithm. [This link](http://www.stanford.edu/class/cs97si/09-computational-geometry.pdf) shows how to find area of the union, but it is not difficult to create elementary (not intersecting) rectangle set, then check for intersection with 'other area'.

If your mask set is dynamic, it might be useful to exploit some data structure like [R-tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R-tree)